# How to use sed with extended regex: group, condition or and bracket character at the same time?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, gnu

I would like use a `sed` extended regex (with option `-r`) for **group**, **condition or** and **bracket character** in avoiding the conflict on the characters `(` and `)` that are several meanings at the same time here.

For example:

```
(a)ccc(b)
```

What is the regex in GNU bash to extract `(a)` or `(b)` of this string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its ambiguous `or condition` here in this case, do :

```
echo '(a)ccc(b)' | sed -r 's/.*(\(a\)).*(\(b\)).*/\1 \2/'
```